# How to run a sub every time I change the cell selection - excel, vba

Tags: vba, excel

**Long story short is: I'd like to run a sub everytime I click in a cell**

I'm stuck here with this sub in excel and I need your help.

I'm writing a VBA code inside **`ThisWorkbook`** area because I'd like this sub to run in every Sheet it has.

My goal is: When I click in a cell (doesn´t matter the Sheet), the sub runs, make some checks and then write in a specific cell (in the same active Sheet) the result.

Is it possible to handle this event?

Thank you.

Comment: is when you click on `cell` or `sheet` ??

Comment: Very Bad idea. Can you please explain what is that check that you want to do? It seems to me that this could be an XY Problem.

Comment: Before anyone asks me what XY Problem is, you may want to see [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Strongly agreeing with @SiddharthRout, even if I've posted an answer for "Q --> A" purposes, I fear you're trying to show the (worse) solution you attempted and not your real problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use the `SheetChange` method of the `Workbook` object:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'run code everytime one of the sheets is changing
End Sub
```

Sorry, I've just read better this: ***When I click in a cell** (doesn´t matter the Sheet), the sub runs, make some checks and then write in a specific cell (in the same active Sheet) the result.*

In that case, you should rather use the `Workbook_SheetSelectionChange`:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    'run code everytime one of the sheets' cells is selected
End Sub
```

However, be careful. The above would run when the *selection* changes, not when you click on a cell. Let's say that "clicking on a cell" is a sub-set of "selecting a cell" (because if you're clicking on a cell you're selecting a cell, but it's not necessarily true that if you're selecting a cell you're clicking on it: you might be selecting it either via VBA code [`Range("A1").Select]` or by moving up/down/right/left with the mouse). So don't forget to manage the difference if you don't want your code to run everytime the selection is changed.

To forecast the next question (how do I distinguish between click or not click?), you may use the `user32.dll` API to get the click:

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer
```

Note: the `PtrSafe` keyword is used to declare the API in 64-bit systems. If you've a 32-bit one, just take it out from the API declaration.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim check As Boolean
    check = GetAsyncKeyState(1) '<-- True if click, False if not click
    If check Then '<-- if click...
        'run code everytime one of the sheets' cells is selected and you intercept a click
    End If
End Sub
```

### To conclude

I quote Siddharth's comment. I've answered this question to show you *how to do what you ask*. If you say what is exactly that you want to do, there will be 95% sure a much better solution than the one I've written above.

And if you want to see why you should never 100% trust the `SelectionChange` (credits to Siddharth for the tip), hide a row in your sheet and then run this macro (put it into a standard module):

```
Sub test()
    Dim r As Range
    r = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
End Sub
```

Even if you're not selecting any cell, the `SelectionChange` event will be fired anyway (so risking a wrong data validation).

Comment: Selection change event can fire even when you are "Not" expecting it. I learned this the hard way many years ago when I was using specialcells

Comment: @SiddharthRout I'd love to hear about an example. I usually avoid it, but never say no to culture.

Comment: Thanks a lot @SiddharthRout, if you don't mind I will add this piece of info to my answer, I find it very useful to be aware of.

Comment: ++ Not only answered the actual question but went the extra mile to explain the hazards as well :)